# Blocking Ads by ISP

Tags: isp

My ISP is inserting an ad on every page I open. (Using JavaScript I guess). I have included a screenshot to show what I am talking about. This is independent of the browser, whether I use chrome, firefox or others the ad does creep in. How can I block it, its irritating ?[image]
Also, for the administrators, I am unable to use Image Uploader in "Ask Question" box, it infinitely shows the uploading box when uploading from computer.

Answer (score 10):

Change the ISP. No seriously, if he really does show that on every page, then he's using somekind of injection...which means that they're altering your traffic.

But to answer your question, I think you can easily get rid of it with [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) and the [Element Hiding Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/).

Answer (score 0):

1. HTTPS Breaks this
2. VPN Bypasses it
3. Change ISP if possible. Verizon have been doing similar to this, its considered really bad practice in the industry and any ISP modifying your traffic doesn't deserve your custom.
4. Extensions will "Hide" the adds to some extent, but you'll still be being tracked by ISP injected tracking cookies most likely, so 3 above still stands.