# Chrome trying to download something?

Tags: google-chrome, download, virus, malware, adware

Lately my Kaspersky antivirus has been showing weird notifications ahout blocking download attempts made from Chrome because it contains adware and such. Here's the log:

```
Event: Download denied
User: ROHITHSDELLG15\Rohith's G15
User type: Active user
Application name: chrome.exe
Application path: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
Component: Web Anti-Virus
Result description: Blocked
Type: Probability of unauthorized software download
Name: https://serasearchtop.com/cfg/fhnlapempodiikihjeggpacnefpdemam/polyfill.json
Threat level: High
Object type: Web page
Object name: polyfill.json
Object path: https://serasearchtop.com/cfg/fhnlapempodiikihjeggpacnefpdemam
Reason: Cloud Protection
```

Why do I get this and why is Chrome trying to download this weird file whenever I open Chrome? Is this some kind of a virus or something? I tried searching for this `polyfill.json` file but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: does the URL mean anything to you?

Comment: Nope never heard of it. I suspect it is some kind of code injection which is trying to download something through chrome but I cannot seem to find its source. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension ID `fhnlapempodiikihjeggpacnefpdemam` used to belong to the "**Easy PiP**" Chrome extension, which has since been removed from Chrome Store – seemingly due to reports of it containing malware (injecting ads to websites, etc). You probably have this extension installed, and should remove it as soon as possible.

There are also reports of the domain `serasearchtop.com` [being used by quite a few extensions](https://palant.info/2023/05/31/more-malicious-extensions-in-chrome-web-store/) containing obfuscated code with unclear purpose. (To be honest the domain immediately *sounds* suspicious to me – it reminds me of those extensions that replace Google frontpage with their own search results.)

Comment: it is plausible, depending on country, that this is being injected by the ISP. see, for example: https://superuser.com/questions/917711/iframe-on-bottom-of-every-page